# HTML form not working with image submit button?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following html form i am testing out.

```
<html>

<head>
<link href = "style.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
</head>

<form action = "test1.php" enctype = "multipart/form-data" method = "POST">
<input type = "hidden" name = "playno" value = "testing">
<input type = "image" src = "uploads/defb.png"  name = "submit" value = "submit"/>
</form>

</html>
```

The following is saved in "test1.php":

```
<?php

$hiddenvalue = $_POST['playno'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "OK";
}
else
{
echo "error";
}

?>
```

In the broswer i am returned the value "testing" when i print $hiddenvalue.  However each and every time it outputs "error" as well, not "OK".

I would greatly appreciate any help.  It is driving me mad!!!
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you are not sending "submit" in post. you should check your $_FILES array. This will might help: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Unless your are uploading files in your form, you should use the enctype `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `multipart/form-data`

Comment: And the attribute `value` is not valid for an image input, it should be removed

Comment: don't check for a post by looking for form fields. `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` is 100% reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `input type="image"`, the browser sends `submit_x` and `submit_y`.

So in PHP, `$_POST['submit']` will not be available, but `$_POST['submit_x']` and `$_POST['submit_y']` will be defined (containing the X/Y coordinates where the image was clicked on).

Comment: Thank you.  You were exactly right.  By the way I wonder if you can help me with my general problem - i know it sounds odd, but i have a page with multiple submit buttons (as images); and basically i want to know how to identify which button has been pressed in the page where the data is being posted to, so i can run the right script.  Is this feasible in principle?

Comment: If you have several image submit buttons, only the one which has been clicked on will be transmitted in the `POST` request. Say you have `submit1` and `submit2` buttons, if you click on `submit1`, you will have `$_POST['submit1_x']` but not `$_POST['submit2_x']`, and if you click on `submit2` you'll have `$_POST['submit2_x']`.

Comment: Cheers.  Yeah i just tested it out.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this inside the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="submit"/>
```

So that it receives the `$_POST['submit']` in your PHP.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type = "image" src = "uploads/defb.png"  name = "submit" value = "submit"/>
```

change to:

```
<input type = "submit"  name = "submit" value = "submit"/>
```

Because input didint have this type

create style for input
HTML

```
<input type = "submit"  name = "submit" value = "submit" id="button" />
```

CSS

```
#button {

background:url("uploads/defb.png");
border:0;
outline:0;

}
```

Comment: `input type="image"` is defined in HTML: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.image.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply only the CSS doesn't appear to be working.  Any ideas?