# Replacing Submit button with image or using a background image for the submit button is not wirking

Tags: php, html, css

I've been struggling with the same problem for some time now. When its just the submit button, all's well. But the moment I am changing it to either an image (replacing type = submit with type = image) or styling an image as a background image, its just not working. Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

## HTML

```
<form method='post' action='contact-form-proc.php' name='contactform' id='contactform'>
    <p>
    <label for='fullname'>Your Name:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='fullname' />
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for='email' >Email Address:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='email' />
    </p>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='' id='submit' />
</form>
```

## CSS

```
<style>
label{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica;
font-size:0.8em;
}
#submit{
    background-image:url('submitP.gif');
    height:2.5em;width:9em;
    border:0;
    display:block;

}
</style>
```

## PHP

```
<?php

if(empty($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "Form is not submitted!";
    exit;
}
if(empty($_POST["fullname"]) ||
    empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
        echo "Please fill the form";
        exit;
    }

$name = $_POST["fullname"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

mail( 'info@xyz.com' , 'New form submission' , 
"New form submission: Name: $name, Email:$email"  );

header('Location: thank-you.html');


?>
```

Comment: `<button name='submit'><img src=".." alt=".." /></button>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button type="submit"><img src="submitP.gif" id="submit"></button>
```

Comment: Daan and Leonzola. I tried as you suggested but the form is still not getting submitted. However, I found out a workable solution, thanks to @MELKIS. You can see it here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667875/html-form-not-working-with-image-submit-button/36061371#36061371". I still dont know the downside to it but so far so good. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I just added this inside the form:

So that it receives the $_POST['submit'] in my PHP.

Thanks to Melkis.